# Is it possible to break a hash-based block cipher?

Tags: encryption, hash, block-cipher, provable-security

Let's define the following block cipher:

$C_n = M_n \oplus H(k + n)$ where $C_n$ is the nth block of ciphertext, $M_n$ is the nth block of plaintext, $H$ is a cryptographic hash function, and $k$ is the secret key.

Decryption can be performed trivially, by computing $M_n = C_n \oplus H(k + n)$.

Assuming a proper mode of operation, such as CBC, how would we go about attacking such a scheme? Is this scheme provably as secure as $H$ is?

Comment: What you describe is not a block cipher, as a block cipher by definition has no notion of position (i.e. $n$). What you're describing is a stream cipher made out of a hash in counter mode (see Salsa20 for a similar construction).

Comment: You'll need an IV somewhere, otherwise you have key reuse issues.

Comment: @Thomas Hence my choice of CBC.

Comment: @SamuelNeves Perhaps my nomenclature is off a little. However, wouldn't introduction of a CBC-like mode of operation preclude it being a stream cipher? Granted it's not strictly in either category. Regardless, the question stands as-is.

Comment: CBC doesn't help you; what you get is something like

Block 0: IV
Block 1: IV ^ M[0] ^ H(K, 0)
Block 2: (IV ^ M[0] ^ H(K, 0)) ^ M[1] ^ H(K, 1)
...

By XORing IV with the first block, the first with the second, etc, you are able to recover M[i] ^ H(K, i)

Comment: @Polynomial I don't understand your want of using CBC - you don't have a block cipher here, since $n$ depends on the position of the block in the plaintext, as Samuel Neves noted. The first line is a mode of operation in itself. CBC depends on the block cipher being, well, a block cipher: in your case, it is not, using CBC (or any other block cipher mode) would be ill-advised.

Comment: A block cipher is a keyed permutation of a single block. So this is no block-cipher, and using it in CBC is a nonsensical operation. It looks like you're using a hash function in CTR mode, to construct a stream cipher.

Comment: I can construct a CBC version of this. The first block is the IV.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a "block cipher" because a block cipher is a key-dependent permutation of the space of blocks of a given size. Here, you handle data by blocks, but the "encryption" part is done by XORing with a value $H(k+n)$ which depends on the key $k$ *and* on the "block number" $n$. So you do not have *one* permutation (for a given key), but a lot of them.

Correspondingly, it is unclear what "CBC" would look like with such a beast. If you imagine it as this:

$$ C_0 = M_0 \oplus IV \oplus H(k+0) $$
$$ C_n = M_n \oplus C_{n-1} \oplus H(k+n) $$

then this is unfortunately hopelessly weak if you encrypt two distinct messages with the same key, even if you use distinct IV -- because the XORs with $IV$ and $C_{n-1}$ can be trivially cancelled by anybody ($x\oplus y \oplus y = x$ for all $x$ and $y$) and you end up with the infamous "two times pad".

As @PaŭloEbermann says, your cipher propose is a stream cipher: it is XORing with a key-dependent pseudo-random stream, generated from the key $k$ but independent of the plaintext. Here, the pseudo-random number generator is built from a hash function. There are several ways to do that, not all being good, because some well-known hash function (MD5 and the whole SHA family) suffer from something known as the [length extension attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack). The "safe" way to build a PRNG out of a hash function is to use HMAC, and that is called HMAC_DRBG. It is a [NIST standard](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf). The same standard defines Hash_DRBG, which is faster (and similar to your proposal) but potentially weaker because it relies on some ill-defined properties of the underlying hash function.

Of course, an IV should be added, and *not* with a kind-of-CBC, as explained above. Rather, replace your key $k$ with $IV||k$ (concatenation of the IV and the key). There again, subtle weaknesses may lurk.

Either way, building a (stream) cipher out of a hash function is *possible*, but it requires care, and often offers rather poor performance. Indeed, hash functions are fast at processing lots of *input data*. Here, you want it to produce lots of *output data* -- and for that, hash functions are not very fast. Even with SHA-1 and Hash_DRBG, the resulting cipher would be slower than a common AES.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that SHA-3 does not suffer from length extension attacks. I'm sure you know this Thomas Pornin, just saying it for any potential reader passing by.

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments, your construction is not what usually is called a block cipher.

A block cipher is a pair of (deterministic) functions with just two inputs: key and plaintext or ciphertext.

Your function has an additional input, the block number.

One could name this a *tweakable block cipher* (i.e. $n$ is the "tweak"):

$$ Enc_k^n(P) = P \oplus H(k, n)$$
  $$ Dec_k^n(P) = P \oplus H(k, n)$$

(This construction is a **quite bad** tweakable block cipher, since it is linear in $P$ and as such easily distinguishable from a pseudorandom permutation, as mentioned in the comment from Ilmari Karonen.)

There are modes of operation for tweakable block ciphers, too, and If I understand right, you just invented your own mode as a combination of counter and CBC mode, like this:

$$ C_n = Enc_k^n(P_n \oplus C_{n-1}) $$
  $$ P_n = Dec_k^n(C_n) \oplus C_{n-1} $$

But with your construction of a tweakable block cipher this reduced to

$$ C_n = C_{n-1} \oplus P_n \oplus H(k || n) $$
  $$ P_n = C_{n-1} \oplus C_n \oplus H(K || n) $$

The effect is that the actual initialization vector can be canceled out simply by XORing it, so it doesn't fulfill the function of making the encryption unique.

---

Another way of viewing your description is as *using a hash function in counter mode*. As mentioned, you'll should include an initialization vector, and this should come as an input into the hash function. One way would be this:

$$ C_n = H(k || IV || n) \oplus P_n$$

Provided your hash function behaves like a pseudorandom function (when used with the key), this will be of similar security as using a block cipher in counter mode.

(The more standard way of counter mode would be to start the $n$ counter input (but not the block number) at the initialization vector instead of 0. I think both ways don't differ in security.)

Comment: It might be worth noting that SHA-2, for example, does *not* become a pseudorandom function when keyed in this way; length-extension attacks may not be applicable in this particular context, but you'd still be making non-standard assumptions about $H$.

Comment: Paŭlo, I know _you're_ perfectly aware of this, but for others reading this answer, it may be worth pointing out that the "tweakable block cipher" $Enc_k^n(P)=P\oplus H(k,n)$ described above is also trivially distinguishable from a pseudorandom permutation, being linear in $P$. As indistinguishability from a PRP is the usual security property expected of a block cipher, I'd be hesitant to call this a block cipher of any kind at all (except maybe a "hopelessly broken" one).